# Why am I getting "internal compiler errors" for adding cout statements in Gem5?

Tags: gem5

I am trying to print data as it is fetched from memory locations by Gem5 simulation. I am editing packet.hh for this purpose. The aim is to be able to edit data in transit.

But even adding cout statements to check the datapointer/data values lead to "internal compiler error".

Should I be using Debug flags instead ? Is this a cout/io-stream thing or does it have something to do with gem5 compilation ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal gem5 commit + your patch or branch on GitHub + gem5 CLI  so we can try to reproduce and understand.

Comment: I just used :
git clone https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5
and then a:
git pull

No CLI was used; I edited code in packet.hh to have some 'cout' statements to see addresses of the data in the packets being handled. Tried to recompile the code using:
scons build/X86/gem5.opt
And was faced with the error.

Comment: I just pulled the code from scratch and tried compiling it:
scons build/X86/gem5.opt

And even from scracth the build is throwing this error:
In file included from build/X86/systemc/utils/vcd.cc:37:0:
build/X86/systemc/core/scheduler.hh: In member function 'virtual void sc_gem5::Scheduler::TimeSlot::process()':
build/X86/systemc/core/scheduler.hh:521:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 }
 ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.

Comment: Please do a `git diff` and upload the patch to the question, otherwise it is hard to reproduce. E.g. I can't reproduce with this patch: https://gist.github.com/cirosantilli/bc08208d20ccde678ca64824310ed7a2 on gem5 revision a060ac86307311587d05d280ee1f4cbdb84fe98a and Ubuntu 19.04 GCC 8.3.0. Always supply revision / patches and your compiler / OS version when reporting build problems.

Comment: diff --git a/src/SConscript b/src/SConscript
index d8014b248..be3a41878 100644
--- a/src/SConscript
+++ b/src/SConscript
@@ -1412,3 +1412,5 @@ if 'perf' in needed_envs:
             CPPDEFINES = ['NDEBUG', 'TRACING_ON=0'],
             LINKFLAGS = Split(ldflags['perf']),
             disable_partial=disable_partial)
+
+DebugFlag("PCKTDATADD")

Comment: If you are developing Gem5 can you point me to the documents which can help me add custom code to edit data in datapackets during Gem5 simulations ?

Comment: Thanks for providing the patch! I'm afraid I don't have the time to try and reproduce right now, but for Build errors, it tends to be simple to  debug, just do a `scons --verbose -j1` build to see the exact GCC command that fails, and then focus on that one. gem5 tutorials are quite limited, but the source is not too bad normally. I haven't touched this area myself so I don't about it.I recommend trying a bit more and sending what you've found to the mailing list with the patch.

Comment: Where can I find the mailing list ??

Comment: See: http://www.gem5.org/Mailing_Lists

Comment: I tried the mailing lists, both dev and users link gave me server time outs. I have posted the question on Quora like the page suggested.... No answers yet.

Comment: Quora is the least likely one to work. Mailing list does work for me daily, did you send to gem5-users@gem5.org ?

Comment: Actually it worked for me and I am awaiting the rest of the instructions, which I should get by mail ?

Comment: While I wait for these instructions: How do I get Gem5 to generate actual output files from the programs I am running on it ? So far I have only run SE based simulations after I did some edits to the source; should I be running FS ?

Comment: What output files do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circumvented this by using cprintf() statements available in Gem5 code.